# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==?

Tags: python, pytorch

I wanted to create a docker image to run my code that needs to run a DNN on GPU. Inside of Dockerfile, I want to install requirements.txt using pip. CUDA 10.1 is installed on the server and I found torch versions that are compatible with CUDA 10.1 from https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/ .
I tried all versions one by one but I encountered an error any time.
For example, one try of requirement file includes:

```
pandas
matplotlib
swig
torch==1.4.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html 
torchvision==0.5.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.4.0 (from versions: 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.4.0
```

Any helps?

Comment: Have you tried installing it with conda ?

Comment: @Droidux No, I would want to run all requirement using pip as far as possible in my docker image. Isn't it possible to install torch using pip?!

Comment: Usually you can, but if you need a specific version maybe you will have to use conda.

Comment: Is your Python version 3.9 or higher?

Comment: @kmkurn python3.9.16. I think the problem is from python version because I tried with python3.5, it worked well but I cannot use python3.5b because of other packages' dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The highest Python version supported by PyTorch 1.4.0 is 3.8 as shown on https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html. That’s why you can’t install it for [your Python 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76471193/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-torch?noredirect=1#comment134839531_76471193). Try installing PyTorch 1.7.1 as the error message suggested.